# Mocking Intrinsic Dependancies in MVC controllers

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, mocking, tdd

I don't understand how you would test something like the following controller.

How would you mock Request?  It seems to me that to mock it you would need to pass in a Request to the method but that is wrong.  Or you would need to inject it into the Controller constructor but that seems wrong too.

I totally get how this would work with ISomethingService or ISomethingRepository but for intrinsic dependancies I just don't get it.

Thanks

```
    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        return View(Request.Browser.Crawler ? "A" : "B");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a mock http context. there are multiple libraries to do so, but you basically need to do something like this:

```
var request = new HttpRequest("", "http://localhost/", "");
var writer = new StringWriter();
var response = new HttpResponse(writer);
var context = new HttpContext(request, response);
```

Comment: Request isn't HttpContext, it is HttpRequestBase

Comment: Also once it is mocked how do I put it in my controller - this is my real issue I think.

Comment: Thanks Zdravko but the property is called Request - eg

var homeController = new HomeController();
var mockHttpRequestBase = MockRepository.GenerateMock<HttpRequestBase>();
homeController.Request = mockHttpRequestBase;

Here though the Request property has no setter - it is read only

Comment: look here, towards the end: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942838.aspx

Comment: Thanks Zdravko - that looks like a really useful article - I shall have a good read of it tomorrow.  Thanks.

Comment: Zdravko - That link was perfect.  I want that to be the answer I accept - can you post this as an actual answer so I can accept?